# How SwiftUI View's body property recalculated on change of @State change?

Tags: ios, swiftui, view, binding, state

I am learning SwiftUI and trying to get one connection:

- View has @State var
- @State is passed to subViews via @Binding
- @State is a propertyWrapper of type Struct, which has wrappedValue, projectedValue.
- @State is confirming to DynamicProperty and has implemented update() method.
- update() might be getting called on setters of wrappedValue and projectedValue.
- now, my que is

1. how swiftUI's View get to know about value change in storage of propertyWrapper  @State var?
2. Is the implementation logic of @state's update(), connected with recalculating the body?

Comment: My assumption is that @State property wrapper may use equivalent of didSet/willSet observers to update the view to which the var belongs to and the Bindings associated to it or some kind of notification observer.

Comment: Yes, I also think that some combine logic can be written beneath.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how swiftUI's View get to know about value change in storage of propertyWrapper @State var?

It's SwiftUI magic. I believe they use singletons for both - state tree and views tree to register existing objects and view, and views became connected to each other. The only thing you need to know, that if you use @State in view's body, then view will be recalculated each time the state changes.

> 2. Is the implementation logic of @state's update(), connected with recalculating the body?

Yes, but indirectly.

Comment: yes, understood about body getting recalculated. But there must be some mechanism ,how they might be connected. Can you elaborate more on this singletons getting connected or if you have any documentation for these singleton structures, it would be a great help.

Comment: There is no documentation for that. It just a guess, but there should be some singleton storage for sure because property wrappers are isolated pieces of code by themselves. Or can be implemented as follows, View protocol is used to generate some code that evaluates all the fields and verifies that they are property wrappers, then it replaces the init method calls for the property wrappers by adding ID parameter value which is unique to each view instance. Hence, when an update comes from a field, it knows the IDs of the views that need to be updated and calls some external method to...

Comment: ... mark views for recalculation - it results in marking all parent views up to the root as `needLayout`, then the engine lays out all the views starting from the root and using depth-first algorithm. There are many ways to do that in other way actually.